# Graph api get members of channel not able get the userId

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

> the response of the get members of the channels has userid, when we debugg it we can find it in the response

but when we try to

```
 var response = await graphClient.Teams[teamid].Channels[channeId].Members
                        .Request()
                        .GetAsync();
        foreach (var res in response)
        {
            var member = new Members();
            member.UserId = res.Id;      //this id is not user id 
            member.FullName = res.DisplayName;
            members.Add(member);
        }
```

The response has userId, not able to get the userID, how do we retrive userId

Comment: I think, you need to use "userId" instead of id.

Comment: hi chetan, it doesn't seem to have userid in the response

Comment: i was able it figure it out, we have to cask it to 
 member.UserId =  ((AadUserConversationMember)res).UserId

Answer (score 1):

I assume your debug code is accessing the beta api, while the your code snippet is using the v1.0 api.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Teams/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-83-1fb73740a315/channels/19:09fc54a3141a45d0bc769cf506d279@thread.skype/members

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#teams('09fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315')/channels('19%3A09fc54a3141a45d0b69cf506d2e079%40thread.skype')/members",
    "@odata.count": 19,
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "id": "MCMjMiMjZGNkMjE5ZGQtYmM2OC00YjliLWJmMGItNGEzM2E3OTZiZTM1IyMxOTowOWZjNTRhMzE0MWE0NWQwYmM3NjljZjUwNmQyZTA3OUB0aHJlYWQuc2t5cGUjIzA3NGU1NmVhLTBiNTAtNDQ2MS04OWU1LWM2N2FlMTRhMmMwYg==",
            "roles": [],
            "displayName": "Lee Gu",
            "visibleHistoryStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "userId": "074e56ea-0b50-4461-89e5-ae14a2c0b",
            "email": "LeeG@M365x2143.onmicrosoft.com",
            "te
...
```

versus the 1.0 api :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Teams/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/channels/19:09fc54a3141a45d0bc769cf506d2e079@thread.skype/members

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Caller does not have the required permissions for accessing this API. AllowedPermissions:'ChannelMember.Read.All,ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All'",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-02-07T23:54:32",
            "request-id": "d82250a3-9637-4626-8afd-499ea3fd519e",
            "client-request-id": "d82250a3-9637-4626-8afd-499ea3fd519e"
        }
    }
}
```

the v1.0 api appears to have more stringent permission requirements.

Comment: even i have same issue , v1.0 has error, but beta seems to work